# Divide and conquer - Algorithm MYST

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

i am trying to understand the following algorithm.
It is a divide and conquer algorithm, which sorts a given array, but can someone help me to understand the idea of this algorithm.
What is the running time of it and why?

Thanks

```
procedure MYST(A, l, r)

  range := r − l + 1

  //returns the least integer greater or equal to x - ceiling function of [x]
  subrange := [2 · range/3] 

  if range = 2 and A[l] > A[r] then

     swap A[l] ↔ A[r]

  else if range ≥ 3 then

     MYST(A, l, l + subrange − 1)

     MYST(A, r − (subrange − 1), r)

     MYST(A, l, l + subrange − 1)

  end if

end procedure
```

Comment: FWIW a trivial variant on this algorithm is *stooge sort*, and the question is equivalent to exercise 8-3 of *Introduction to Algorithms* by Cormen, Leiserson, and Rivest.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea seems to be to do something like merge sort but avoid actually merging. To do this we essentially first sort the first 2/3rd of the array, then the next 2/3, and then the first 2/3rd again. The important thing is that after the first two steps, anything that should lie in the last 1/3 of the sorted array gets there (so the third step sorts the rest and then we are done). To see this, note that anything that is among the top 1/3 of the elements is in the second half of the first 2/3 after the first step (as less than 1/3 of the elements are more than it), and so it is also affected by the second step.

Running time: T(2) = c1 (constant).

T(n) = 3T(2n/3) + c2.

So by the master theorem, T(n) = O($n^{log_{3/2}3}$)